# HTTP 500 Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Failed to start application for Admin sendmail

Tags: joomla-4.x, external-script, joomla-mail

I am working with Joomla 4.2.2

I have a custom script which i previously used in Joomla 3.*, from this i am sending mail using send-mail.

For front it's working fine but on admin side it can not detect the current application (Admin Application) and it gives me the error -> Failed to start application.
[image]

```
Exception
Exception:
Failed to start application

  at /html/joomla/libraries/src/Factory.php:140
  at Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()
     (/html/joomla/libraries/src/Mail/Mail.php:503)
  at Joomla\CMS\Mail\Mail->isSendmail()
     (/html/joomla/libraries/src/Factory.php:682)
  at Joomla\CMS\Factory::createMailer()
     (/html/joomla/libraries/src/Factory.php:439)
  at Joomla\CMS\Factory::getMailer()
     (/html/joomla/administrator/invoiceCopy.php:698)
```

How i can set application globally as admin application while i use the admin environment.

Comment: In Joomla 4 the application could be get via $this->app but in only works at **controller level.**

You can check how it's done by viewing contact controller at '/components/com_contact/src/Controller/ContactController.php', _sendEmail function.